# Eclipse: Converting JAR file into project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project converted into executable jar which is hosted and running just fine.

How to convert this jar src into a project in eclipse so that i can debug and do modifications to the existing files?

I have tried importing as maven, but it imports the libraries inside the META-INF, and i can't see any class files or pages.

This is the project structure  JD-GUI,

[image]

Comment: If there are no pages or .java files, you can't do a lot.  What about the "com"  directory?

Comment: @SteveSmith, COM has the java packages(classes) like fasterxml, google, sun,keypoint

Answer (score 0):

Use [JD GUI](http://jd.benow.ca). Open the application, drag and drop your JAR file into it.

Comment: I can open the project. The issue is how to bring it as a working project in eclipse by importing it

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam You want to get source code of this JAR file?

Comment: i want the src to be opened as a project in eclipse

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam When you got the source code of this JAR then you can directly import it as a project.

Comment: That is what i mentioned in the question, i can't able to open it as maven project.